# How can I search all files which are NOT in .gitignore?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have to do a major search-and-replace update across multiple repos...

In my initial search, I get back over 30,000 results.  Many of these results are inconsequential and shouldn't be touched because they are 3rd-party tools.  Most of these tools are ignored in the repos by .gitignore.

So, I tried creating a new Search Scope which could include only non-.gitignored files only to find I must manually select all folders...

...or must I?

Is there a way to create a scope or otherwise search only non-.gitignored files?

NOTE: Do not confuse my request with PhpStorm/Intellij's "ignore" feature.  I am specifically asking about .gitignore.

Comment: Might be a good feature request for the [.ignore plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore).

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder - I've commented on an existing feature request for this, here: https://github.com/hsz/idea-gitignore/issues/178 -- if it's something you want, please make your voice heard there as well.